# iOS - How to test deep linking in the Appstore using branch.io

Tags: ios, branch.io

I am using branch.io for integrating the deep linking in my iOS App. The fact is, if the app not yet installed on the iPhone, it will redirect to the Appstore page. I have done the settings in the branch.io(Link settings -> iOS -> Custom URL).

My question is how can I debug the incoming deep link info in the Appdelegate after installed the App from the Appstore page. Can I update the diawi URL for testing in the Custom URL(Link settings -> iOS -> Custom URL). Will branch.io supports diawi?.

Please do the needful on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: you should be able to use your Diawi URL for the Custom URL in Link Settings. That will *replace* the Appstore page for all of your links when the visitor doesn't have your app installed, so don't forget to switch it back before public release.

You can debug the incoming deep link data by examining the params object that is returned when you initialize a Branch session. See this page for details: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/ios/#start-a-branch-session